# How to make variable for using For Loop

Tags: ms-access, vba

How can I put textboxes in a for loop in VBA Access?

```
txta1=a(1)
txta2=a(2)
txta3=a(3)
```

We had in FoxPro:

```
txta&i =a(i)
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please read how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
for i=1 to n
me.controls("txta" & i)=a(i)
next i
```

Comment: Thank you but I couldn't solve my problem.This code is working:
Sub test()
   Dim a(40) As Integer
   a(1) = "1"
   a(2) = "2"
   a(3) = "3"
   DoCmd.OpenForm "FR_Certificate", acViewLayout
  With Forms![FR_Certificate]
  .txta1.Value = a(1)
  .txta2.Value = a(2)
  .txta3.Value = a(3)
  End With
  End Sub

but when I change 
.txta1.Value = a(1)
.txta2.Value = a(2)
.txta3.Value = a(3)

with 

For i = 1 To 3
Me.Controls(."txta" & i.value) = a(i)
Next i

I got syntax error.

Comment: Thank you very much.  How can I write       textBox1.Text in C# using variable i instead of number 1?

Answer (score 0):

```
Thank you but I couldn't solve my problem.This code is working:
Sub test()
 Dim a(40) As Integer
 a(1) = "1"
 a(2) = "2"
 a(3) = "3"
 DoCmd.OpenForm "FR_Certificate", acViewLayout
With Forms![FR_Certificate]
.txta1.Value = a(1)
.txta2.Value = a(2)
.txta3.Value = a(3)
End With
End Sub

but when I change 
.txta1.Value = a(1)
.txta2.Value = a(2)
.txta3.Value = a(3)

with 

For i = 1 To 3
Me.Controls(."txta" & i.value) = a(i)
Next i

I got synntax error.
```

Comment: You have modified the code of @h2so4 to something without meaning.

Comment: @ali if you want to use the dot . to refer to .txt1,.txt2,.txt3 use the following syntax  .controls("txt" & i)=a(i) (ie remove the me in the instruction)

Comment: .Controls("txta" & i).Value = a(i)   Works. Thank you very much h2so4.